# How to add multiple expect calls in a loop

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to test a function using gtest. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
**Function to Test:**
void ClassAdd::Display(int num) {
    for (int n = 1; n <= num; ++num) {
        status = ClassInterface_.Function1(...);
        ...
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            status = ClassInterface_.Function2(...);
            ...
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++) {
            status = ClassInterface_.Function3(...);
            ...
        }
    }
}

**Test Code:**
TEST(Test, TestName) {
    InSequence s;
    for (int num = 1; num < 3; ++num) {
        EXPECT_CALL(*(mockClassInterface_.get()), Function1(_))
            .WillOnce(Return(true));
        EXPECT_CALL(*(mockClassInterface_.get()), Function2(_, _))
            .WillRepeatedly(Return(true));
        EXPECT_CALL(*(mockClassInterface_.get()), Function3(_, _, _, _))
            .WillRepeatedly(Return(true));
    }
    ClassAdd* test1 = new ClassAdd();
    ASSERT_TRUE(test1->Display(3));
}
```

I know why it is not working. It expects **Function1** followed by **Function2** and **Function3**. But in the next iteration, EXPECT_CALL is not being called and returns false by default. Hence, the test is failing. Here is the error I see when I run:

```
tried expectation #0: EXPECT_CALL(*(mockClassInterface_.get()), Function1(_))
Expected: the expectation is active
Actual: it is retired
Expected: to be called any number of times
Actual: never called - satisfied and retired
```

Any tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: We can't really debug pseudo-code. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58925454/edit) to have a [Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read [this link](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/for_dummies.md), especially the section "Using Mocks in Tests"

From what I understand of your pseudo-code, you have a `Display` function that calls `Function1`, `Function2` and `Function3` a certain amount of time. 
To test that these functions are correctly called, and to add a return value, you should rather use the "Times" function.

For instance:

```
EXPECT_CALL(*(mockClassInterface_.get()), Function1(_)).Times(3).WillRepeatedly(Return(true));
```

This call means "I want the Function1 function to be called 3 times with any parameter, and it shall always return true".

Also note that by using Times, you don't need to use a for loop to define your EXPECT_CALL expectations.